# Assign a function to a variable in JQuery

Tags: jquery

I am trying to developing my own progress bar. At this moment, I want to update my progress bar when I click a button. I have assigned a variable to a function which is called when the button is clicked.

The application doesn't run ok because the function returns an object and I need a integer. I have tried to make a conversion, but I can't. This is the code:

```
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {    
            var val = $('#boton').click(function () {
                return Number(Math.floor(Math.random() * 100 + 1));
            });
            $("#porcentaje").text(val + '%');
            $('#progressBar div').css("width", val.toString() + "%");          
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="formulario">
        <div id="progressBar">
            <div></div>
        </div>
        <div id="porcentaje">
        </div>      
        <input type="button" id="boton" value="Start" />
    </form>
</body>
```

[image]

How can I fix it?

Thanks.

Comment: Your variable "val" is the function you assign to the click event of the button not the value the function returns. I think you need to learn a bit more about functions in javascript... Look at the answer from Shomz.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`val` is not what you think in this case. `.click()` method return the reference to the jQuery selector object, which is why you're not getting the numeric value. See this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var val = 0;
  $('#boton').click(function() {
    val = Number(Math.floor(Math.random() * 100 + 1));
    $("#porcentaje").text(val + '%');
    $('#progressBar div').css("width", val.toString() + "%");
  });
  setInterval(function(){
     alert("Val is currently: " + val);
  }, 5000);
});
```

```css
#progressBar div {height: 10px; background: #eee; width: 0}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="formulario">
  <div id="progressBar">
    <div></div>
  </div>
  <div id="porcentaje">
  </div>
  <input type="button" id="boton" value="Start" />
</form>
```

Comment: At first, my code was like you have wrote. The problem of this code is val is always 0 except for the moment when button is clicked, and I want to store the value of val outside the click button function.

Comment: My example *does* store the val outside that click callback function. What are you doing with it? I've updated my answer so that you can see the actual value of `val` in the alert every 5 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

`.click()` will return the same jQuery object on which it was called on, that is why you are getting `Object` as the output.

Instead you need to just move the code which sets the text and css inside the event handler like

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var val;
  $('#boton').click(function() {
    val = Number(Math.floor(Math.random() * 100 + 1));
    $("#porcentaje").text(val + '%');
    $('#progressBar div').css("width", val + "%");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="formulario">
  <div id="progressBar">
    <div></div>
  </div>
  <div id="porcentaje">
  </div>
  <input type="button" id="boton" value="Start" />
</form>
```

Comment: At first, my code was like you have wrote. The problem of this code is val is always 0 except for the moment when button is clicked, and I want to store the value of val outside the click button function.

Comment: @user2656997 then just make the `val` to be a closure variable instead of making it as a local one... then inside the dom ready handler value of `val` will change....

Comment: @user2656997 but if you want to access `val` outside of the dom ready handler then declare val(`var val` ) outside of the dom ready handler instead of inside